# Running multiple Python programs fills up /dev/mapper/gregorbr--lnx--vg-root 55G 52G 55M 100% /

Tags: server, partitioning, ssh, python, disk-usage

I have a ubuntu server 12.04.5 LTS that I use to run multiple python programs that uses ssh.  I have it set up so it just prints to screen, so it shouldn't take up any space at all.

Here is they stats when I first SSH into it:

```
  System load:  0.0                Processes:           250
  Usage of /:   94.8% of 54.52GB   Users logged in:     2
  Memory usage: 11%                IP address for eth0: 172.18.137.9
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for eth1: 10.17.9.222
```

The output of `df -h`:

```
/dev/mapper/gregorbr--lnx--vg-root   55G   52G   55M 100% /
udev                                5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                               1.2G  716K  1.2G   1% /run
none                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                5.9G  144K  5.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                           236M   32M  192M  14% /boot
```

Once I reboot the box I get all of the free space back, is there a way I can get the hard disk without rebooting it?  I have no large files on the server and the program doesn't save anything so what is taking up space so I can't figure out what is taking up space on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use either df or the [disk usage analyzer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) to find which files are taking up all of the space. Then you can figure out what's creating them.